# Path Integral Formulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

The contribution to the propagator from a particular trajectory is 
$e^{\frac{iS[x(t)]}{ћ}}$. Does anyone knows how to get to this $e^{\frac{iS[x(t)]}{ћ}}$? As in showing me any reliable source regarding this because I try searching for how to come up with it but to no avail. Sorry for this stupid question as I just started.

Comment: Do you mean the derivation of that factor? The canonical reference is Feynman & Hibbs. I don't know if it will be rigorous enough for you.

Comment: Yes I talking about the factor, the exponential one. Feynman&Hibbs? I try searching for it and the search result mostly shows books on QM and PIF